# how can i get tailwind css classes to apply in jest render result

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jestjs, tailwind-css

I have run into a case where I am testing for a capitalised string in my jest rendered html. the capitalisation is occurring through tailwind, but it is not being applied in the jest render function. I cannot find a lot of information online about it. My set up is basically a boilerplate t3 app. has anyone managed to get tailwindcss to apply to the jest renderer and if so how did they do it